# How to use esc_attr__ with custom translation function?

Tags: translation

I just made a built-in translation function to help users to translate their theme from theme options.

Usually my functions works great as follow:

```
<?php _e( 'No Comments', 'mytextdomain' ); ?>
```

becomes:

```
<?php echo __myfunction( 'no_comments' ); ?>
```

My question is related to `esc_attr__` and I'm stuck here... 
How the following code should look using custom translation function?

```
esc_attr__( 'No Comments', 'mytextdomain' )
```

Where should I place my translation function `__myfunction` ? Will be corect the following code?

```
esc_attr__myfunction( 'no_comments' )
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand your question. If you have made your own tranlation function you could choose whatever name you want. I don't get where the problem is. I think you could use `esc_attr__( __myfunction( 'no_comments' ) )` or `esc_attr_e( __myfunction( 'no_comments' ) )` for echoing the result.

Comment: Yes, you understood perfectly!Please post your comment as a reply so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your function returns the translated string, you could pass the translation function as parameter for `esc_attr()` and `esc_attr_e()`:

```
esc_attr__( __myfunction( 'no_comments' ) );
esc_attr_e( __myfunction( 'no_comments' ) );
```

But `esc_attr__()` and `esc_attr_e()` will perform translation tasks that you don't need because you handle the translation at your own, so I think it is better to use `esc_attr()` only:

```
esc_attr( __myfunction( 'no_comments' ) );
```

and

```
echo esc_attr( __myfunction( 'no_comments' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`esc_attr_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr_e):

```
esc_attr_e( $text, $domain )
```

> *Displays translated text that has been escaped for safe use in an attribute. Encodes `<` `>` `&` `"` `'` (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote, single quote). Will never double encode entities.*

Comment: I guess you missed my question: I need to use my custom translation function. Where I can place `__myfunction` using `esc_attr__`?

Comment: Please add context of your question, because gettext is for `string`, not for functions. And why do you need such a function there? And why not the `esc_attr_e()` function is doing your job. Please edit your question and add more context and logic.